# Moq SignalR Client events

Tags: testing, mocking, signalr

I have a service that uses the SignalR .Net Client to communicate with the server, and I want to add some test to check how the client will react to connection problems (Slow-Internet, Intermittent Connection, No connection at all), the problem is that I don´t know how to mock this so that I can create the tests.

I´m new at mocking so I´m having a hard time with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to design your code so that you only have dependecy to the IHubProxy interface

You can look at my .NET client library to see how it can be solved
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNet

In my case some of the code needed the actual concrete HubProxy so what I did was to create a factory that returns a IHubProxy, in that way I could do the stuff that had depedency to the concrete type fro that factory and all other code relied on dependecy to IHubProxy that way I could mock the concrete HubProxyFactory and the HubProxy code

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNet/Bootstrap/Factories/HubProxyFactory.cs

After the code is adjusted its just a matter of some Mock magic, in my case

```
WhenCalling<IHubProxyFactory>(x => x.Create(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<Action<IHubConnection>>.Is.Anything, Arg<Action<IHubProxy>>.Is.Anything, Arg<Action>.Is.Anything, Arg<Action<Exception>>.Is.Anything, Arg<Action>.Is.Anything))
                .Callback<string, Action<IHubConnection>, Action<IHubProxy>, Action, Action<Exception>, Action>((u, c, started, reconnected, f, connected) =>
                {
                    started(proxy);
                    reconnectedCallback = reconnected;

                    return true;
                })
                .Return(proxy);
```